# Net_GeoIP returns a fatal error

Tags: php, apache, geolocation, geoip

I have installed net_geoip on my web host and am encountering the error `Fatal error: Class 'Net_GeoIP' not found in /home/heyitspr/public_html/beta_simplecraft.biz/index.php on line 3` when I run the script that is posted below:

`$geoip = Net_GeoIP::getInstance('GeoIP.dat', Net_GeoIP::SHARED_MEMORY);`
`$country_name = $geoip->lookupCountryName($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);`

`print_r ($country_name);`

I am new to installing plugins with apache so please explain it in simpler terms. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you have not included your **`GeoIP`** library. Try including it on your **`index.php`** code

```
include_once('GeoIP.php');
```

Comment: I don't get any errors now but the output is just a blank page.

Comment: Can you have a look here. http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.networking.net-geoip.lookupcountryname.php

Comment: Where would I get the net/geoipdb.dat file?

Comment: Ok, I just installed the Database and tried the code on the website but I still get a blank page. Are there any other extensions I need to run Net_GeoIP?

Comment: Looks like I had the wrong DB installed. Thanks for your help!